# Flutter PageView prevent swiping when there's no widget

Tags: flutter, widget, flutter-pageview

On iOS the user can swipe right or left even when there's no item there, it rebounds but the user can still see part of a white screen. Is there anyway to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

This is related to the physics your widget is using. Try this on your PageView:

```
  physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
```

Comment: It still shows the white screen albeit with more bouncing.